# Xamarin.forms embedded image not shown on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am building an app with xamarin.forms. Because the image is to be displayed on both devices, I choose to use an embedded image and followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=macos#embedded-images) tutorial.

The build action of my image is configured to EmbeddedRessource

[image]

I created the custom class :

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace PianoTraining
{
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Source))]
    public class ImageResourceExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (Source == null)
                return null;

            return ImageSource.FromResource(Source, typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        }
    }
}
```

And I load my image via the XAML:

```xml
<Image x:Name="ChordStatusImage" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.66,0.33" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional,YProportional" />
```

The only slightly different thing is in the xmlns step: I cannot set the xmlns property as specified in the tutorial because I am already setting it to another value to use a custom renderer to display AdMob ads in my app (I followed [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/google-admob-display-ads-in-xamarin-forms/) tutorial). But it doesn't seem to be a problem on Android.

I set the resource for the image programmatically:

```cs
ChordStatusImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("PianoTraining.assets.images.wrongChord.png");
```

The problem is that my image is never shown on iOS and can't figure out why.

[edit]
Precision about how I set the source

The page where the image is loaded is called `PianoTrainingPage` so I have a class called `PianoTrainingPage`. The image displayed should change depending on whether the chord is detected or not, and a function is called to load the right image. But because the images weren't displayed, I only set one image programmatically in that function for testing purposes.

I tested several calls to `ImageRessource.FromRessource` and none of theme solved my problem:

- `ChordStatusImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("PianoTraining.assets.images.wrongChord.png",typeof(ImageResourceExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);` (The one from the tutorial) --> The image is displayed on Andrid but not on ios
- `ChordStatusImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("PianoTraining.assets.images.wrongChord.png",typeof(PianoTrainingPage).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);` (because I thought that maybe I was giving the wrong class to typeof) --> The image is displayed on Android but not on ios
- `ChordStatusImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("PianoTraining.assets.images.wrongChord.png");` (using default value for the second parameter) --> The image is displayed on Android but not on ios

In my code, I used the third version because it is the last I tested

Comment: if you are setting the image source in code the XAML extension and markup are not needed.  And the last code snippet where you set `ChordStatusImage.Source` does not look anything like what is shown in the tutorial.  You are not providing a reference to the shared assembly where the images are located.

Comment: AbsoluteLayout has 4 nummers i think , position with and heigt . called Layoutbounds https://xamgirl.com/absolutelayout-in-xamarin-made-simple/

Comment: @BasH the last 2 numbers are optional and their values are `AutoSize` if not provided

Comment: @BasH I don't think that's relevant to the question

Comment: @Jason The last parameter doesn't change anything in the behaviour: my image is shown on Android and not on iOS

Comment: you're not following what I'm telling you.  `ImageSource.FromResource("somename");` will load the image from the default iOS/Android image location.  If you want to load from the **shared** Forms assembly, you have to include a reference to that assembly.  See the example in the tutorial you linked to: `ImageSource.FromResource("WorkingWithImages.beach.jpg", typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)`

Comment: @Jason The thing is I did use this form of the call (replacing `MyClass` with the class from where the call is made) and it doesn't change anything, maybe I am not using the right name for `MyClass`?

Comment: I have no idea because you have **not posted that code**.  You have posted a bunch of code for a markup extension that you are not actually using.  Please post the correct, relevant code.  Also verify that you are using the correct ResourceID as shown in the tutorial

Comment: *"can't figure out why"* Look in VS "Output" pane. Is there a relevant error or warning? I also recommend doing the tutorial exactly as shown (in a new project) - does the image show on iOS? I notice that you use FromResource slightly differently than the tutorial. I suspect that Resource path you use is not quite what iOS expects.

Comment: *"I cannot set the xmlns property as specified in the tutorial because I am already setting it to another value to use a custom renderer"* - not a problem: use a different name. Add multiple `xmlns:foo` `xmlns:bar` lines, one for each namespace you need to reference in your XAML. You can use any name after `xmlns:` - whatever is convenient. Its like a "nickname" for that namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jason and ToolmakerSteve mentioned in the comment, there are two ways to solve the problem .

#### Xaml

Add another `name` for your namespace , it is allowed to add same namespace with different names.

```
xmlns:a="clr-namespace:PianoTraining"
xmlns:b="clr-namespace:PianoTraining"
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:PianoTraining"
```

And then set the reference to the class `ImageResourceExtension`  ,like

```
<Image Source="{a:ImageResource PianoTraining.assets.images.wrongChord.png}" />
```

#### Code behind

Just provide any class which is included in the current assembly ,like `ImageResourceExtension` .

```
ChordStatusImage.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("PianoTraining.assets.images.wrongChord.png",typeof(ImageResourceExtension ).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was doing things well from the beginning, with the `typeof` value, but for some reason, the data from the mic of my mac were not provided to the ios simulator. I recompiled my binding library and everything is okay now.

Thank you for the help